# Schmidt decomposition of coupled oscillators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

Consider a system of two coupled oscillators, with Hamiltonian ($\hbar = m = 1$):

\begin{align}
\mathcal{H} = \frac{1}{2}(p_1^2 + \omega_0^2 x_1^2) + \frac{1}{2}(p_2^2 + \omega_0^2 x_2^2) +\frac{1}{2}k(x_1 - x_2)^2.
\end{align}

Changing to normal coordinates ($y_1 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(x_1-x_2)$ and $y_2 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (x_1 + x_2)$), one gets the wave functions to be a product of two decoupled oscillators with eigenfrequencies $\omega_1^2 = \omega_0^2 + 2k$ and $\omega_2^2 = \omega_0^2$. In particular the ground state is
\begin{align}
\Psi_0 = \left(\frac{\omega_1\omega_2}{\pi^2} \right)^{1/4} \exp(-\frac{1}{2}[\omega_1 y_1^2 + \omega_2 y_2^2] ).
\end{align}

It is known that we can perform a Schmidt decomposition on the system, and write
\begin{align}
\Psi_0 = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-\tanh \eta)^n}{\cosh \eta}\Phi_n(x_1) \Phi_n(x_2),
\end{align}
where $\exp(4\eta) = \omega_1/\omega_2$ and $\Phi_n$ are the oscillator states for a frequency $\tilde{\omega} = \sqrt{\omega_1 \omega_2}$.

I'm not too sure if my question makes sense, but it is: how do we know a priori that the Hilbert space of the system which is a product of two oscillators of frequency $\omega_0$ (is it ??):
\begin{align}
H = H_{SHO,\omega_0} \otimes H_{SHO,\omega_0}
\end{align}
can be also written as
\begin{align}
H = H_{SHO,\omega_1} \otimes H_{SHO, \omega_2}
\end{align}
as in the decoupled case, and also as
\begin{align}
H = H_{SHO,\tilde{\omega}} \otimes H_{SHO,\tilde{\omega}}
\end{align}
as in the last step?

In other words, I wish to decompose the Hilbert space into a tensor product of smaller subspaces, but how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All harmonic oscillator Hilbert spaces of different frequencies are unitarily equivalent by virtue of the [Stone–von Neumann theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93von_Neumann_theorem). This theorem implies also that  these Hilbert spaces are unitarily equivalent to the free particle Hilbert space; where the transformation is given by means of the Bargmann transform, please , for example, see the definition in the introduction equation (1) of [Olafsson-Ørsted](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.45.9227) article. Thus if the algebra of operators is composed (of a finite number of copies) of the canonical commutation relations, one already knows that the quantization Hilbert space is a tensor product of the same number of oscillator Hilbert spaces